# Bullet connect by line having same color on mousehover amChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I want to connect all same color bullets by line on mouse hover. In normal condition I want to show only small bullets. When someone mouse hovers then they connect to each other by line.

```
             var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "dataProvider": [{
                "x": 1,
                "aaa": 2,
                "bbb": 4,
            }, {
                "x": 2,
                "aaa": 1.1,
                "bbb": 5,
            }],
            "valueAxes": [ {
                "maximum": 6,
                "minimum": 0,   
              } ],
            "startDuration": 0.5,
            "graphs": [{
                "id": "g1",
                "balloonText": "aaa[[category]]: [[value]]",
                "bullet": "round",
                "title": "aaa",
                "valueField": "aaa",
                "color": "#000000",
                "lineAlpha": 1,
            }, {
                "id": "g2",
                "balloonText": "bbb [[category]]: [[value]]",
                "bullet": "round",
                "title": "bbb",
                "valueField": "bbb",
                "color": "#000000",
                "lineAlpha": 1,
            }],
             "categoryField": "x",
              "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "position": "left",
              }
            } );
```

Comment: Please help me i am stuck @martynasma

Comment: Thak you so much @martynasma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged question with `jQuery` I'm going to provide a solution that uses it. Without it, the solution would get much more complicated.

The solution itself relies on enabling of class names in the chart, by using [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames). When enabled, the chart will attach class names to various chart elements, like bullets, lines, etc.

We're going to use those class names with `jQuery` to select them and manipulate their opacity.

First, we attach `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to bullets using `.amcharts-graph-bullet` selector. We then find out which graph the bullet belongs to (chart adds both generic class names like `amcharts-graph-bullet` and id based class names like `amcharts-graph-g2`.

Then we can target lines of the specific graph, to apply opacity (or rather `stroke-opacity` attribute, since regular CSS does not work the same in SVG) to the line part of the specific graph.

Please note, that his approach will not work at all in old IE browsers (IE8 and down), since they do not support SVG.

Here's a working chart:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "x": 1,
    "aaa": 2,
    "bbb": 4,
  }, {
    "x": 2,
    "aaa": 1.1,
    "bbb": 5,
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "maximum": 6,
    "minimum": 0,
  }],
  "startDuration": 0.5,
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "aaa[[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 20,
    "title": "aaa",
    "valueField": "aaa",
    "color": "#000000",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "lineThickness": 3
  }, {
    "id": "g2",
    "balloonText": "bbb [[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 20,
    "title": "bbb",
    "valueField": "bbb",
    "color": "#000000",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "lineThickness": 3
  }],
  "categoryField": "x",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "position": "left",
  }
});

/**
 * Add events
 */
$("#chartdiv").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".amcharts-graph-bullet", function(e) {
  
  // find out graph id
  var graphClass = $(this).closest("g.amcharts-graph-line").attr("class").split(" ").pop();
  
  // figure the opacity based on event type
  var opacity = e.type === "mouseenter" ? 1 : 0;
  
  // set opacity of the related lines
  $("." + graphClass +" .amcharts-graph-stroke").attr("stroke-opacity", opacity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

And here's [the same chart on CodePen](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b5b4ea2e2e7cd882dd58fc4a6ab70d9c).